# jQuery mouseenter simple effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fade a `<div class="front">` outand a `<div class="back">` in on hover, and when users hovers out I need to revert , fade out **back** and fade in **front**, however my `<div class="back">` does not fadeout on mouseleave.

Sorry the the newbie question but i'm not sure why this code isn't working. It is because I need to trigger the mouseenter on the back event when the front fades out?

http://jsfiddle.net/8xo8c5pn/

**HTML**

```js
$(".front").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).next().removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});

$(".back").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).prev().removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});
```

```css
.on{
    display:inherit;
}
.off{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <div class="front">
   <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/jadensadventures/images/5/54/Pokemon-Ash-s-Pikachu-Riley-Sir-Aaron-s-Lucarios-pokemon-guys-10262907-563-579.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120902022940">
    <div class="cover">
       <div class="">Hello</div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="back off">
<div class="back box-style-1 off-color-bg">
 <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i><p></p>
 <h2>im the back</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>

 </figure>
```

Comment: try this as well: http://jsfiddle.net/8xo8c5pn/4/ I would suggest giving the item div a fixed height/width so that it doesn't keep resizing and messing up the mouseenter and mouseleave events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 element with class back so use `.back.off`  instead of just `.back`

try this

```
$( ".front" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).next('.back.off').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});

$( ".back.off" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
    $(this).prev('.front').removeClass('off').addClass('on');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8xo8c5pn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".back").hide(); //hide back initially
  $(".front").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".back").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $(".back").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".front").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

});
```

```css
.back,
.front {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure>
  <div class="front">
    <img src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/jadensadventures/images/5/54/Pokemon-Ash-s-Pikachu-Riley-Sir-Aaron-s-Lucarios-pokemon-guys-10262907-563-579.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120902022940">
    <div class="cover">
      <div class="">Hello</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back off">
    <div class="back box-style-1 off-color-bg">
      <i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
      <p></p>
      <h2>im the back</h2>
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: in addition, you need to ensure the elements are the exact same size.  when you move the mouse down, for example, the background div still shows

Answer (score 0):

try this, Use hover function instead mouseenter and leave:

```
<div class"album">
    <div class"front">
    </div>
    <div class"cover" style="display:none;">
    </div>
</div>

$( ".album" ).hover(
function() {  // IN
    $(this).find('.front').hide();
    $(this).find('.cover').show();
},function() { // OUT
    $(this).find('.front').show();
    $(this).find('.cover').hide();
});
```